# Invalid value with datetime library

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I want to calculate time difference.
I don't understand why I received value 1380.0

I have data

```
    date    user    action  id
0   2019-12-07 22:52:23 AnonymousUser   LOGIN   NaN
1   2019-12-07 22:52:25 admin   VACANCY 21.0
2   2019-12-07 22:52:28 admin   VACANCY 20.0
3   2019-12-07 22:52:31 admin   VACANCY 19.0
4   2019-12-07 22:52:35 admin   VACANCY 18.0
5   2019-12-07 22:52:38 admin   VACANCY 16.0
6   2019-12-07 22:52:42 admin   VACANCY 15.0
7   2019-12-07 22:52:45 admin   VACANCY 13.0
8   2019-12-07 22:52:48 admin   VACANCY 17.0
9   2019-12-07 23:02:12 AnonymousUser   VACANCY 16.0
```

and I calculated

```
class UserInfo:
    def __init__(self, date, user, action, user_id):
        self.date = date.split()[0]
        self.time = date.split()[1]
        self.user = user
        self.action = action
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.start_date = None
        self.end_date = None

    def date_delta(self):
        print(self.end_date.split()[1])
        print(self.start_date.split()[1])
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(self.end_date.split()[1], '%H:%S:%M') - datetime.datetime.strptime(self.start_date.split()[1], '%H:%S:%M')


    def __str__(self):
        return "{};{};{};{};{}".format(self.date, self.time, self.user, self.action, self.user_id)
```

then I filled dict

```
users = {} 

for row in df.iterrows():
    cur_date = row[1]["date"]
    cur_user = row[1]["user"]
    cur_action = row[1]["action"]
    cur_id = row[1]["id"]

    if cur_user not in users:
        users[cur_user] = UserInfo(cur_date, cur_user, cur_action, cur_id)
        users[cur_user].start_date = cur_date
    else:
        users[cur_user].end_date = cur_date
```

Finally I calculated time difference for user "admin"

```
admin = users["admin"]
print(admin.date_delta().total_seconds())
```

I received output 
22:52:48
22:52:25
1380.0

**I expected 13 seconds, why I received 1380?**

Comment: I think it is in milliseconds

Comment: @Stack why do you think so?  
From documentation
>> total_seconds() Return the total number of seconds contained in the duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong format string to parse the time string.

`%H:%S:%M` should be `%H:%M:%S`

```
import datetime

s1 = '22:52:48'
s2 = '22:52:25'
print( (datetime.datetime.strptime(s1, '%H:%S:%M') - datetime.datetime.strptime(s2, '%H:%S:%M')).total_seconds() )
# 1380
print( (datetime.datetime.strptime(s1, '%H:%M:%S') - datetime.datetime.strptime(s2, '%H:%M:%S')).total_seconds() )
# 23
```